# Build failed with an exception, Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm having very rough time with upgrading old react-native project to new react-native version (0.51.0), when I'm trying to build its throwing errors, my current setup:

**build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" // temp for windows
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.minddiagnostics"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-charts-wrapper')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-linear-gradient')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-vector-icons')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation (project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
    implementation project(':ReactAndroid')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**Error im getting:**

```
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\tmp\MindDiagnostics\app\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Szop\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\react-native-0.51.0.aar\28a14fcd800d8cdfdc050753acdceffe\jars\libs\infer-annotations-4.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [infer-annotations-4.0.jar:com/facebook/infer/annotation/Expensive.class]))
```

I'm using Android Studio 3 and Windows, followed official documentation on upgrading a react native project and used react-native upgrade, after that, I used [`Building React Native from source`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html)

Comment: Did you get somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following on **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
android {...}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native'
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that the version on `details.useVersion` should match the version in `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'`